# Trigger em MySQL para locação de filmes?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Eu preciso de uma ajudinha porque o professor disse que não é pra utilizar `FUNCTIONS` e `PROCEDURES`, APENAS o `TRIGGER`. Segue imagem do que ele está pedindo. Eu realmente não estou conseguindo fazer. Pra mim tinha que existir antes uma `FUNCTION` onde ele verifica se o ID do filme inserido está na tabela de locação e verificar a data de devolução a partir disso. Se for maior que `0000-00-00` pode alugar, senão o `TRIGGER` retorna mensagem avisando que o filme está alugado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código que você já fez e o erro que está dando.